# SQL Query to fill missing gaps across time and get last non-null value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table in my database:

```
Month|Year | Value
   1 |2013 | 100
   4 |2013 | 101
   8 |2013 | 102
   2 |2014 | 103
   4 |2014 | 104
```

How can I fill in "missing" rows from the data, so that if I query from 2013-03 through 2014-03, I would get:

```
Month|Year | Value
   3 |2013 | 100
   4 |2013 | 101
   5 |2013 | 101
   6 |2013 | 101
   7 |2013 | 101
   8 |2013 | 102
   9 |2013 | 102
  10 |2013 | 102
  11 |2013 | 102
  12 |2013 | 102
   1 |2014 | 102
   2 |2014 | 103
   3 |2014 | 103
```

As you can see I want to repeat the previous `Value` for a missing row.

Comment: what are your reasons for doing this and what have you tried so far? if you give your question more context and show your efforts you'll get a better answer than.

Comment: @Tanner The purpose is to compare data that doesn't have the data for a month as well because in our table its like this to reduce the data in the table.

Comment: The simplest method would be to have a lookup table with all months and years to join to. Value would return null if that date combination didn't exist, at which point you would calculate the Value to insert.

Comment: Use a Calendar table which contains every day of every month of every year for the period of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf2cb/50) of this solution for you to play with.

Essentially it creates a Work Table @Months and then Cross joins this will all years in your data set. This produces a complete list of all months for all years. I then left join the Test data provided in your example (Table named TEST - see SQL fiddle for schema) back into this list to give me a complete list with Values for the months that have them. The next issue to overcome was using the last months values if this months didn't have any. For that, I used a correlated sub-query i.e. joined tblValues back on itself only where it matched the maximum Rank of a row which has a value. This then gives a complete result set!

If you want to filter by year\month you can add this into a WHERE clause just before the final Order By.

Enjoy!

**Test Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( Month tinyint, Year int, Value int)

INSERT INTO TEST(Month, Year, Value)
VALUES
   (1,2013,100),
   (4,2013,101),
   (8,2013,102),
   (2,2014,103),
   (4,2014,104)
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @Months Table(Month tinyint)
Insert into @Months(Month)Values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);


With tblValues as (
  select Rank() Over (ORDER BY y.Year, m.Month) as [Rank], 
          m.Month, 
          y.Year, 
          t.Value
  from @Months m
  CROSS JOIN ( Select Distinct Year from Test ) y
  LEFT JOIN Test t on t.Month = m.Month and t.Year = y.Year
  )
Select t.Month, t.Year, COALESCE(t.Value, t1.Value) as Value
from tblValues t
left join tblValues t1 on t1.Rank = (
            Select Max(tmax.Rank)
            From tblValues tmax 
            Where tmax.Rank < t.Rank AND tmax.Value is not null)

Order by t.Year, t.Month
```

Comment: The answer you gave is correct but if the data is for 2012 and 2014 then i will get only for 2012 1-12 and 2014 1-12

Comment: In which case you may need to replace the "Select Distinct Year from Test" with another work table filled with the years you are interested in. e.g. "Select Year from @Years". This can be populated from your data in a number of ways. via a loop. via a rownumber starting from min(year) or even manually like I have done for months.