# Select results through date range, including null where results do not exist

Tags: php, sql-server

**This is Microsoft SQL, NOT Mysql.**

I have a table that holds invoice data for shipments sent to our customers.

For example, the data may look like this:

```
INVOICE DATE | QUANTITY | PRODUCT | VENDOR ID
2014-07-31   | 25       | Oranges | 12
2014-08-12   | 14       | Apples  | 12
2014-09-01   | 135      | Oranges | 12
2015-07-04   | 18       | Oranges | 12
2015-07-12   | 35       | Apples  | 12
```

As you can see, there are gaps in the data where we did not send an order to that customer for a specific month.

I am attempting to get a list of months so I can display this on a chart (chartJS to be specific) so I need null values where those records do not exist so we have a string of 12 values, even if they're all zero for the given year.

Right now, we are accomplishing that with disparate queries (VERY VERY BAD) in a PHP loop, like so

```
while($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $query = "Select sum(quantity), month, year
        From Table
        where month = $i
        and year = $year
        and vendorID = 12"
}
```

This results in a data set such as the following, where we get each month and if there are no results we get zero.

```
month | year | quantity
...   | ...  | ...
6     | 2014 | 0
7     | 2014 | 25
8     | 2014 | 14
9     | 2014 | 135
10    | 2014 | 0
....  | .... | ....
```

Unfortunately, that requires 12 queries for every year we want to display. I would like to be able to get that same data in ONE query.

Unfortunately, the updated query is only returning a result when an invoice date exists. Is there a way to loop through all possible months using SQL, rather than PHP in order to get this information using an aggregate query?

I've gotten the following query to work but it only gives me results where an invoice date exists:

```
Select sum(quantity), month, year
from table where VendorID = 12
and InvoiceDate between '1/1/2014' and '12/31/2014'
GROUP BY year, month
```

Result:

```
Quantity | Month | Year
25       | 7     | 2014
14       | 8     | 2014
135      | 9     | 2014
53       | 7     | 2015
```

As you can see this only provides results with a value, rather than all months with zeros.

## Solution

Thanks to the contributors I have a solution query that works, sort of a combination of both suggestions

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
Set @StartDate = '7/1/2014'
SET @EndDate = '12/1/2015'

;with cal as (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [Date])
    FROM cal
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
)
select coalesce(a.qty, 0) as qty, 
DATEPART(month, cal.[Date]) AS [month], 
DATEPART(year, cal.[Date]) AS [year] from
(
    SELECT sum(qty) as qty, 
    [month], 
    [year]
    from ship_table
    WHERE vendorID = 12
    group by [year], [month]
) A
right join cal ON DATEPART(month, cal.[Date])=A.[month]
AND DATEPART(year, cal.[Date])=A.[year]
```

Comment: you can't have the db produce data where none exists. if you want non-existent dates to be in the results, you'd need to have those dates in a table you can join against. e.g. make a temp table, fill it with all possible dates in your range, join against that.

Comment: maybe the best way is to add the missing values to the result after the query (using php)

Comment: @MarcB What's the impact on doing that versus the structure we have now, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Write a CTE that produces all the months and JOIN to it.   This question has been asked and answered many many times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to fill missing gaps across time and get last non-null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932159/sql-query-to-fill-missing-gaps-across-time-and-get-last-non-null-value)

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't need to get a previous value, I need to get a zero, so I can't create a table as in that example that has data.

I also simplified this question for the asking, but our query needs to span 15 months, which means the month iterator will reset as will the year.

So I would need, for example, dates such as July 1, 2014 through December 31, 2015. I can't just do 1-12 in the same year, unfortunately

Comment: Ignore the part about getting the previous value, and just use the part about joining to a table variable or cte that has all the values you want.   With a little logical thinking, you can adapt the answer to your question.

Comment: MSSQL is not my RDBMS of choice. If this were Mysql I could just use group_concat and be done with it :( Unfortunately I'm stuck with the data I have.

Can you provide an example? I do not know how to iterate through a date on a monthly basis, and the answer given only inserts values, not dates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86709/discussion-between-oranges13-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below query. I've used pivot to fill in the month numbers.
I am assuming either the year remains constant i.e. `2014`  (which justifies using `ISNULL(year,2014)`) or can be derived in some manner from parameter like `YEAR(@startmonth)`

I've also created a sql fiddle for demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9dc17/2

```
select ISNULL(A.quantity,0) as quantity,cal.Num as Month,ISNULL(year,2014) from
(Select sum(quantity) as quantity, month(InvoiceDate) as month, year(InvoiceDate) as year
from [table]
where VendorID = 12
and InvoiceDate between '1/1/2014' and '12/31/2014'
GROUP BY year(InvoiceDate), month(InvoiceDate)) A
right join
(select mon,num from
    (
    select 1 as [Jan],2 as [feb],3 as [mar],4 as  [apr],5 as [may],6 as [jun],7 as [jul],8 as [aug],9 as [sep],10 as [oct],11 as [nov],12 as [dec]) s
    UNPIVOT
    (
    Num for Mon in ([jan],[feb],[mar],[apr],[may],[jun],[jul],[aug],[sep],[oct],[nov],[dec])
    )up) cal
    on A.month=Cal.Num
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer I was driving at.

Based on the query code in your question, I assume your table has columns named "Month" and "Year", and they can be used the same way as in your query.

Assuming you will pass a StartDate and EndDate parameter to your query, so you can get any date-range:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [Date])
  FROM cte
  WHERE [Date] <= @EndDate
)
Select 
  sum(quantity), 
  DATEPART(month, cte.[Date]) AS [month], 
  DATEPART(year, cte.[Date]) AS [year]
from table t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN cte
  ON DATEPART(month, cte.[Date])=t.month
  AND DATEPART(year, cte.[Date])=t.year
where VendorID = 12
GROUP BY   DATEPART(month, cte.[Date]) AS [month], 
  DATEPART(year, cte.[Date]) AS [year]
```